# React Bootstrap V3, make row have height of max height component in two column view

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a two column view for some components as such

```
<Grid fluid={true}>
  <Row>
    <Col sm={6}>
      <Component>
    </Col>
    <Col sm={6}>
      <Component>
    </Col>
    <Col sm={6}>
      <Component>
    </Col>
    <Col sm={6}>
      <Component>
    </Col>
    ....
  </Row>
</Grid>
```

The component can be different sizes. The problem I'm running into is that when a component in the left column is taller in height than the component to the right, then the component that is supposed to go on the left in the next row, ends up filling in the space left open by the smaller component on the right.

[See problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQPJZ.png)

I want the left component for row 2 to go under the left component for row 1 and then the following right component for row 2, to be directly adjacent to the left component and not take up any of the extra white space left by the right component for row 1.

Any solutions would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced it and there isn't such issue and it works as you expecting (maybe you added some stylesheets that caused the issue, or using `<Component>` instead of `<Component/>` causes the issue):

[image]

(Note that i used latest version of `react-bootstrap`, and `Grid` is renamed to `Container` in this version.)

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
const Component = props => (
  <div
    style={{
      height: props.height ? props.height + "px" : "auto",
      background: "#35f",
      margin: "10px",
      color: "white"
    }}
  >
    component
  </div>
);
export default () => (
  <Container fluid>
    <Row>
      <Col sm={6}>
        <Component height={200} />
      </Col>
      <Col sm={6}>
        <Component height={100} />
      </Col>
      <Col sm={6}>
        <Component height={50} />
      </Col>
      <Col sm={6}>
        <Component />
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Container>
);
```